# Objective-C how to get an image from a url

Tags: objective-c

Am having some difficulty getting an Image from a url, and then displaying it in an image well in the interface.

This is the code I'm currently using, it doesn't work and compiles with no errors:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nataliedee.com/061105/hey-whale.jpg"];

NSString *newIMAGE = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:newIMAGE]];
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in image data as a string to a method that is trying to use that string as the name of the image, which of course doesn't exist.

What you need to do is create an `NSData` object from your URL `dataWithContentsOfURL:`, once you have the `NSData` object use this to create the `UIImage` via `imageWithData:`.

Comment: but I'm not doing iPhone dev, should it just be NSImage via imageNamed for mac dev?

Comment: @James Use `NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:theDownloadedData];`